# Does a non-empty locally closed subset of a $k$-scheme of finite type always contain a closed point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field.
Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $k$.
We denote by $X_0$ the set of closed points of $X$.
Let $Y$ be a locally closed subset of $X$.
Is $Y \cap X_0$ non-empty whenever $Y$ is non-empty?

**Motivation**
See my comment to Avi Steiner's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615255/a-condition-for-a-locally-closed-subset-of-a-k-scheme-of-finite-type-to-be-clo).

Answer (score 2):

Write $Y=Z \cap U$ with $Z \subseteq X$ closed and $U \subseteq X$ open. Now we may view $Y$ as an open subset of the closed subset $Z$ of $X$. We make $Z$ into a closed subscheme of $X$. Then it is again of finite type over $k$, and we have $Z_0 = X_0 \cap Z$. Thereby we reduce the problem to open subsets. But then it follows from a corollary of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, stating that the closed points are dense.

Comment: How do you prove that $X_0$ is dense in $X$ when $X$ is not affine?

Comment: Denseness is a local property. Also remember that $X_0 \cap U = U_0$ for every open $U$ in $X$, since $x$ is closed iff $k(x)$ is finite over $k$.

Comment: How do you prove that $x$ is closed iff $k(x)$ is finite over $k$?

Comment: I've just posted a question on this subject.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615709/is-the-set-of-closed-points-of-a-k-scheme-of-finite-type-dense

Comment: If $x$ is closed, then $k(x)$ is finite over $k$ by Zariski's Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma). Conversely, assume that $k(x)$ is finite over $k$. Consider an open affine neighborhood $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, so that $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, and $x$ corresponds to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Then $\mathrm{Quot}(A/\mathfrak{p})$ is finite over $k$, so that also $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is integral over $k$. Since $k$ is a field, it then follows that the integral domain $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field, i.e. $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal. Hence, $x$ is closed.

Comment: How do you prove that a closed point of an affine open subset of $k$-scheme $X$ of finite type is a closed point of $X$?

Answer (score -1):

I believe any one dimensional local ring is a counter example: The generic point is open and not closed.

Comment: Could you please give an explicit example: finite type over $k$ seems difficult to achieve.

Comment: Sure: $k[t]_{(t)}$.

Comment: That is not of finite type over $k$.

Comment: Ahh yes, you are correct. My geometry is a little rusty. Suppose $k$ is finite though, then $k[t]_{(t)}$ is of finite type. Am I right?

Comment: Nope. If a local ring is of finite type over $k$, its maximal ideal must be nilpotent.
By the way, you better write @hisname in the head of your comment to ping him. Otherwise he might not notice it.

Comment: Nice comment about nilpotency, dear @Makoto. I'd prove it by noticing that the local ring is Jacobson. I'm sure you have a better proof ...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg [I'm sure you have a better proof] Not at all. It's almost the same thing as Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Answer (score -2):

As Martin Brandenburg's answer shows that we may suppose that $Y$ is a non-empty open subset of $X$.
Then $Y \cap X_0$ is non-empty because $X_0$ is dense in $X$ by the proposition of my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615709/is-the-set-of-closed-points-of-a-k-scheme-of-finite-type-dense).